# Performing a function on a set of protein sequences, would like to make it that my output will also include the name of sequence from a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

```
Code:
Seq_List=open('test.trunc..txt','r')#uses tab files from uniprot copied into notepad 250 work
data = Seq_List.readlines()
N, P = [], []
for line in data:
        values = [str(s) for s in line.split()]
        N.append(values[0])
        P.append(values[1])
N.remove('Entry')
P.remove('Sequence')
print(P)
Sequencedict = {} 
for key in N: 
for value in P: 
    Sequencedict[key] = value 
    #P.remove(value) 
    break  
print(Sequencedict)
print(Sequencedict.values())
def idr (P):
for i in P:
    x= i.replace('Q','e').replace('R','b').replace('S','e').replace('T','e').replace('Y','e')]
    #print(x)#gives the converted sequences
    #print(type(x))#output x is a list
    for g in x:
        v=g.count('h')
        #print(v)
        y=g.count('e')+g.count('a')+g.count('b')
        #print(y)
        z=len(i)
        #print(values)
        #print(y/z)
        if y/z>.10: #and v/z<.10: #e/tot>.60=sumo
            print(i)
            print(Sequencedict.keys())#reprint i and swap based of dict
            print(v)
            print(y)
            print(y/z)
            print('Disorder Promoting=Yes')
        #else:
            #print('Disorder Promoting=No')
        idr (P)


  Output:
  ['MSRTIVALILLGLAALA', 'MARFLVALALFGVVAMTAA', 'MARLFVAVALFGVVAFAAAEK']
  {'P0CU41': 'MSRTIVALILLGLAALA', 'P0CU39': 'MSRTIVALILLGLAALA', 'P0CU40': 'MSRTIVALILLGLAALA'}
  dict_values(['MSRTIVALILLGLAALA', 'MSRTIVALILLGLAALA', 'MSRTIVALILLGLAALA'])
  MSRTIVALILLGLAALA
  dict_keys(['P0CU41', 'P0CU39', 'P0CU40'])
  14
  3
  0.17647058823529413
  Disorder Promoting=Yes
  MARFLVALALFGVVAMTAA
  dict_keys(['P0CU41', 'P0CU39', 'P0CU40'])
  17
  2
  0.10526315789473684
  Disorder Promoting=Yes
  MARLFVAVALFGVVAFAAAEK
  dict_keys(['P0CU41', 'P0CU39', 'P0CU40'])
  18
  3
  0.14285714285714285
  Disorder Promoting=Yes
```

Wrote a generic program that will take a tab file of protein names and sequences perform a function on the sequence and then give me an assigned output. Where I am having difficulties is trying to link the dictionary embedded names with the conditional "if" output specific to each individual processed sequence. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: share the input file and the desired output file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a few problems with your code. First I guess you want to combine the first key in your list N with the first value from your list P, next the second key from N with the second value from P and so on? The code you actually have does not do that. At the moment it just applies to every key, the first value of P. I would suggest to zip the values together:

```
Sequencedict = dict(zip(N,P))
```

Next you can pass the whole dictionary to your function and iterate over the items:

```
def idr(your_dictionary):
    for key, value in your_dictionary.items():
        value = value.replace('Q','e').replace('R','b').replace('S','e').replace('T','e').replace('Y','e')
        v = value.count('h')
        y = value.count('e')+value.count('a')+value.count('b')
        z = len(value)
        if y/z>.10:
            print(value)
            print(key)
            print(v)
            print(y)
            print(y/z)
            print('Disorder Promoting=Yes')

idr(Sequencedict)
```